# How to get Correct QueryString Value from URL having UNICODE value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url, query-string, unicode-string

I have a field with nvarchar datatype to store UNICODE value. This field is bound to Repeater Control from which i am redirecting to other page on clicking the link. When this field contains the numeric value in field then, i get the correct QueryString and it displays the Redirected page. But, When it contains some unicode charater(Other than Number or English Character) then it show the value '?????' in QueryString of 'fhn'. How to get this UNICODE QueryString value as it is and display result?

In Repeater ItemTemplate:

```
<b>घर क्र./House No.</b><%# Eval("HouseNumber")%> 
<a href="AddressList.aspx?li=<%=Request.QueryString["li"].Trim().ToString() %>&fhn=<%# Eval("HouseNumber")%" target="_blank">या पत्यावरील </a>
```

In .cs file:

```
string HouseNumber = Request.QueryString["fhn"].ToString().Trim();
```

//here i get the '????' value if it contains unicode value.

Help appreciated!

Comment: What about `string HouseNumber = Encoding.GetBytes(Request.QueryString["fhn"].ToString().Trim());`?

Comment: Sorry @mattytommo! Encoding.GetBytes does not exist...! It has Encoding.GetEncoding & Encoding.GetEncodings methods!So, any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to something more like this:

``` <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->``<configuration> ```
`<system.web>`
`<customErrors mode="Off"/>`
`<globalization fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>`
`</system.web>`
`</configuration>`

Comment: Thanks @Jaya Prakash Rokkam
for reply! but,the whole page shows '????' wherever i use Unicode on Page! After adding the settings in web.config as you mentioned above..!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be a more precise. You could set request and response encoding in your web.config file:

```
<system.web> 
    <globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" /> 
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks @Imran Rizvi for replying! But, Unfortunately the whole page shows '????' wherever i use Unicode on Page and after adding the settings in web.config as you mentioned above..! :-(

Comment: try with Server.Web.UrlEncode and UrlDecode methods, use encode before adding query string value to url and decode before reading the same.